# OVH - Executing cron

Tags: cron, ovh

I'm trying to setup cron on OVH web host.
The script to be executed is located in :
/home/[login ftp]/www/script.sh

So I've created a cron on the OVH interface with this setup:

- Command to execute : ./www/script.sh
- Language : Other

The script contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

If I execute the script on ssh console, everything is fine.

But, with the OVH cron, no way :

```
[2021-04-05 21:36:02] ## OVH ## END - 2021-04-05 21:36:02.246979 exitcode: 255
[2021-04-05 22:05:00] ## OVH ## START - 2021-04-05 22:05:00.778348 executing: /homez.1003/[login ftp]/www/test.sh
[2021-04-05 22:05:00] Cannot execute command for user '[login ftp]': Exec Format Error (err: -1)
[2021-04-05 22:05:00]
[2021-04-05 22:05:00] ## OVH ## END - 2021-04-05 22:05:00.813826 exitcode: 255
```

Lastly, here is my .ovhconfig file :

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=7.4
http.firewall=none
environment=production
container.image=stable64
```

I've tried many configurations without no success.

FYI, I also have an .htaccess on the root folder (so in /home/[login ftp]) that redirect on an other path. Could this have any consequence on the cron execution ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you make your script executable ? `chmod +x ~/www/test.sh` ? Is there any special charater in your script ?

Comment: Yes, the script has the correct rights. And there's no special character as the script works when I launch it in the SSL console.

Comment: Are you also able to run the script from the "llogin ftp" user from shell? Or are you using root or sudo to make your tests?

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the error message saying that the command cannot be executed for user "Login ftp". It seems that you have to define the user before executing a command. So I've tried sudo [mylogin] echo "Hello World".

But it didn't work :
Cannot execute command for user '[mylogin]': Exec Format Error (err: -1)

I also tried with files in UTF8, UTF8 without BOM and ANSI. No more success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a support answer today that "Other" cronjobs are no longer working and menu entry will be gone soon.

Comment: Thank you for this information. So the only way remains a php file...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is not possible to execute an sh file on ovh/cron. I've tried with php file and it works like a charm :

```
<?php
shell_exec('echo "Hello World"');
?>
```

I'm pretty surprise of that because there many example on the web showing an sh executable as cron. Maybe ovh has changed it policy recently.